# Multiple lines on jqplot with dynamic data assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqplot

I am trying to use jqplot to display multiple series ( line) on chart. I am calling java servlet and getting data in String format. Later in javascript, I am assigning that String with split function to array and passing that value to jqplot, datarenderer. If I am assign static values in JS, it working but when I assign values received from Servelt, it's not showing. So seems somehow, I am doing something wrong while asigning and concating arrays. Below is the code -
It's displaying only one line and that has data as per data[] array. It's ignoring values from data2 array.
Can anyone please help. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var sineRenderer = function() { 
var list = "'2013-7-21',9740000:'2013-7-30',107640000:'2013-12-30',117640000:'2013-11-30',98940000"; 
//this String will be return result from Ajax call. I have hardcoded it to test
var datatemp = list.split(":");

var data2 = [[]];
data2[0].push([datatemp[0]]);
data2[0].push([datatemp[1]]);
data2[0].push([datatemp[2]]);
data2[0].push([datatemp[3]]);

var data = [[]]; 
data[0].push(['2012-7-21',9740000]);    
data[0].push(['2012-8-24',9940000]);
data[0].push(['2012-10-26',10040000]);
data[0].push(['2012-12-29',20000000]);

var array1=data.concat(data2);

return array1;  };

  $.jqplot('chartdiv',  
  [],
{ dataRenderer: sineRenderer,
title:'Exponential Line',
  axes:{
  yaxis:{tickOptions: {
    formatter: function(format, value){
        return MillisecondsToDuration(value);
    }
},label:'Cosine',          
labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,          
labelOptions: {            
fontFamily: 'Georgia, Serif',            
fontSize: '12pt'          
}}, 
  xaxis:{          
  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,           
  tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d, %y'},          
  label:'Angle (radians)',          
labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,          
labelOptions: {            
fontFamily: 'Georgia, Serif',            
fontSize: '12pt'          
}  
  }},
  series:[{show: true, label: 'Level 1', color:'#5FAB78'},{show: true, label: 'Level 2'}],
  legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'outside',
        location: 'ne',     // compass direction, nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w.
        xoffset: 12,        // pixel offset of the legend box from the x (or x2) axis.
        yoffset: 12, 
       // pixel offset of the legend box from the y (or y2) axis.
    },
  highlighter: {        
  show: true,        
  sizeAdjust: 7.5      
  },      
  cursor: {        
  show: false      
  }
})
});

function MillisecondsToDuration(n) {
    var dtm = new Date();
    dtm.setTime(n);
    var hours = Math.floor(n / 3600000);
    var minutes = dtm.getMinutes();
    var seconds = dtm.getSeconds();
    return $.jqplot.sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds);        
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are splitting `list` into strings of `"'2013-7-21',9740000"` and such, that's not the same as an array of `['2012-7-21',9740000]`.

Comment: Hi oGeez, Thanks for your prompt response. Is there a way, I can add these strings into array similar to data[].

Comment: It would be better if you could alter your server-side code to return valid JSON

Comment: Thanks oGeez. I am working to find a json format which can be parsed into multiple series.

Comment: Hi oGeez, I have fixed this by using JSON. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user3151498 how do you fix it ? I am having same kind of issue, i tried json but till now i am not successful to send series data that contains single quote. Would you please share your solution ?